# How to bind to checkbox checked event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

How to run javascript code if checkbox is checked?

checkbox is defined as

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="Maksja_piiratudes" name="Maksja_piiratudes" 

onfocus="if(typeof this.ischanged=='undefined') this.ischanged=false" onblur="summarefresh()" onclick="dataChanged(this)">
```

I tried

```
$(function () {
  $("#Maksja_piiratudes").on("change", function() {

alert('checkbox is checked');

});  // end on change
}); // end $
```

But this runs also if checkbox is unchecked.
How to run code only if checkgox is selected ?

Bootstrap 3, jquery, jquery UI are used.

Comment: One line was missing. I edited question and added missing line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `checked` property of an checkbox input.

```
$(function()
{
    $('#Maksja_piiratudes').on('change', function()
    {
        if (this.checked)
        {
            alert('checkbox is checked');
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

I prefer the vanilla style more.. so just in case someone needs it:

```
document.querySelector('#Maksja_piiratudes')
        .addEventListener('change', function()
{
    if (this.checked)
    {
        alert('checkbox is checked!');
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: `event.target === this`

Comment: This probably binds into all checkboxes in page. How to run code for specific checkbox only defined by html is in question? This checkbox has unique id and name attributes `id="Maksja_piiratudes" name="Maksja_piiratudes"`

Comment: That was an example before you edited your code, see my last update

Comment: @Andrus [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the **first element** which matches the selector

Comment: @Kai Thank you. Using native code without jquery looks nice. jquery events are used for other elements by bootstrap and maybe in custom code. So both native and jquery event handlers are in same page. Is this OK, I read that this is not recommended

Comment: Good question, it's better to not mix them indeed. So in your case, jQuery would be the better option.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$(function () {
    $("#Maksja_piiratudes").on("change", function() {    
       if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
           alert('checkbox is checked');
       } //end if
    });  // end on change
}); // end $
```

If you want to make it global for all checkboxes use the below:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {    
       if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
           alert('checkbox is checked');
       } //end if
       else {
           alert('checkbox is unchecked');
       }
    });  // end on change
}); // end $
```